# C - Trying to go back to previous line in the file

Tags: c, file, line, back

I have to read a text file which can begin with optional comments. In practice I have to skip any line at the beginning of the file that doesn't begin with '@' or '>'.
In my test case the file looks like:

```
# Sun Jul 12 22:04:52 2009 /share/apps/corona/bin/filter_fasta.pl --output=/data/results/solid0065/primary.20090712170542775 
# Cwd: /state/partition1/home/pipeline
# Title: solid0065_20090629_FC1_Tomate_Heinz_4_5_Kb_Tomate_Heinz_4_5_Kb_01
>125_963_316_F3
T1230330231223011323010013
```

So I have to skip the first 3 line (but in general I have to skip n lines). I have to repeat this with 2 or 4 files [which are inside FILE** inputFiles]. I've tried with this loop:

```
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 5000);
if (buffer == NULL)
    notEnoughMemory();

for (i = 0; i < (cIn-1); i++){
    fgetpos(inputFiles[i], &position);
    fgets(buffer, 4999, inputFiles[i]);
    while ((buffer[0] != '@') && (buffer[0] != '>')){
        fgetpos(inputFiles[i], &position);
        fgets(buffer, 4999, inputFiles[i]);
    }
    fsetpos(inputFiles[i], &position);
}
```

Where cIn is number_of_input_files + 1.
Trying to debug it the loop correctly stops after it reads the fourth line. But when I use setpos it doesn't go back to the beginning of the fourth line as I'd expect, but at the middle of the third.
In fact if, exactly after the fsetpos(), I print buffer after these operations:

```
fgets(buffer, 4999, inputFiles[i]);
fgets(buffer, 4999, inputFiles[i]);
```

I get:

```
FC1_Tomate_Heinz_4_5_Kb_Tomate_Heinz_4_5_Kb_01
>125_963_316_F3
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just skip processing the lines you are not interrested in:

```
for (i = 0; i < (cIn-1); i++){

    while (fgets(buffer, 4999, inputFiles[i])){
       if(buffer[0] == '@' || buffer[0] == '>') {
          puts(buffer);
        }
        /* else do nothing*/
    }
}
```

Then you just replace the `puts(buffer);` with the code you need to handle the valid lines.
(allthough, from your example it sounds like you rather want to only ignore lines starting with a `#`, ?)

Comment: It modifies the input file, doesn't it? Unluckily I can't do that.

Comment: @Alex It just reads through the file to the end, the on disk file is not modified.

Comment: I read fputs sorry. Then I'm not sure how to read what I puts()... with a scanf()?

Comment: @Alex puts() was just an example, and so that you can verify you're getting at the proper lines of text. You are supposed to delete that puts() call, and replace it with the actual code you want to run for each of the valid input lines that you are reading. The line is in the `buffer`, so e.g. call myfunction_that_does_something(buffer);. if this is not what you need, please explain what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Since I didn't understand why fseek and fsetpos didn't work when they were supposed to (copy and pasted some working source code and still getting errors!) I decided to change things a little and doing something similar to your suggestion. Still wondering why fseek isn't working though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fgetpos(); fsetpos();` you might use
`fseek(inputFiles[i], -strlen(buffer), SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: It doesn't work. If I try to use _fseek(inputFiles[i], -strlen(buffer), SEEK_CUR);_   _fgets(buffer, 4999, inputFiles[i]);_  Then what I get is:   **C1_Tomate_Heinz_4_5_Kb_Tomate_Heinz_4_5_Kb_01**

Comment: i just tried it and it worked  
       'fgets(buffer, 4999, file);
 while ((buffer[0] != '@') && (buffer[0] != '>')){
  
  fgets(buffer, 4999, file);
 }
 
 fseek(file, -strlen(buffer), SEEK_CUR);
 fgets(buffer, 4999, file);
 printf("%s",buffer);'

Comment: The only problem that I can imagine is that fgets isn't null terminating properly, but that would be really weird.

Comment: strlen(buffer) is 16, which is correct (the ">" line ends with a '\n'), so that's not the problem. I believe there's something wrong with the current position in the file... Mah...

Comment: This answer is wrong for files opened in text mode.  [Per **7.21.9.4 The ftell function**, paragraph 2 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."

Answer (score 1):

(IMHO )Best is to read the entire file into one big buffer (mmap is also an option, if available) , then find and fix the line endings and fasta headers. This will also reduce memory fragmentation. And it simpifies the 'parser' a lot.

EDIT: added source (it is not perfect, but last time I checked it, it worked ;-) Might be incomplete, I snipped it from a larger program.

```
struct fastapart {
  char * name;
  char * data;
  unsigned size;
  struct roedel *friends;
  };
struct fastafile {
  size_t totsize;
  char *tot;
  unsigned count;
  struct fastapart *parts;
  int *alloc;
  };

struct fastafile * read_complete_fasta(char *name)
{
int rc,state;
struct fastafile * result;
size_t pos,len,cnt,idx;
struct strbuff *fwd=NULL,*rev = NULL;

result = malloc (sizeof *result);
if (!result) return NULL;
result->tot = read_complete_file(name , &result->totsize);
if (!result->tot) goto failfree;

result->count = 0;
result->parts = NULL;

for (pos=cnt=state=0; pos < result->totsize; ) {
switch (state) {
case 0: /* find first '>' */
  if (result->tot[pos] == '>') { pos++; state=2; continue; }
  pos += strcspn( result->tot+pos, "\n" );
case 1: /* not found: sync to newline */
  if (result->tot[pos] == '\n') { pos++; state=0; continue; }
  else pos++;
  continue;;
case 2: /* Got '>'; grab name */
  len = strcspn( result->tot+pos, " \t\n" );
  if (cnt >= result->count) {
    size_t siz;
    siz = result->count ? 2* result->count: 16;
    result->parts = realloc( result->parts
      , siz * sizeof *result->parts);
    for (  ; result->count < siz;result->count ++) {
      result->parts[cnt].name = NULL;
      result->parts[cnt].data = NULL;
      result->parts[cnt].friends = NULL;
      result->parts[cnt].size = 0;
      }
    }

  result->parts[cnt].name = result->tot+pos;
  result->parts[cnt].name[len] = 0;
  pos += 1+len;
  len = strspn( result->tot+pos, " \t\n" );
  pos += len;
  state++;
  continue;
case 3: /* grab data; for the moment, throw away reversed data */
  if (result->tot[pos] == '>') {
    if (fwd) {
      memcpy(result->parts[cnt].data, fwd->data, fwd->used ); result->parts[cnt].size = fwd->used;
      result->parts[cnt].data [ fwd->used ] = 0;
      fwd->used = 0; }
    if (rev) {
      /* memcpy(result->parts[cnt].data+result->parts[cnt].size, rev->data, rev->used );  */
      rev->used = 0;
      }
    if (result->parts[cnt].data) cnt++;
    pos++; state=2;
    continue;
    }
  len = strcspn( result->tot+pos, "\t\n" );
  if (!len) { /* empty line; what to do? skip it! */
    fprintf(stderr, "Empty\n" );
    pos++; state=1;
    continue; }
  if (!result->parts[cnt].data) {result->parts[cnt].data = result->tot+pos;  }
  fwd = strbuff_add(fwd, result->tot+pos, len);
  pos += len;
  if (result->tot[pos] == '\t' ) {
    pos += strspn(result->tot+pos, " \t" );
    len = strcspn( result->tot+pos, "\n" );
    rev =  strbuff_add(rev, result->tot+pos, len);
    pos += len;
    }
  pos += strspn(result->tot+pos, " \t\r\n" );
  }}
if (state == 3) {
  if (fwd) {
    memcpy(result->parts[cnt].data, fwd->data, fwd->used ); result->parts[cnt].size = fwd->used;
    result->parts[cnt].data [ fwd->used ] = 0;
    fwd->used = 0;
    }
  if (rev) {
    /* memcpy(result->parts[cnt].data+result->parts[cnt].size, rev->data, rev->used );  */
    rev->used = 0;
    }
  if (result->parts[cnt].data) cnt++;
  }
  /* final realloc */
result->parts = realloc( result->parts, cnt * sizeof *result->parts);
result->count  = cnt;
free (fwd);
free (rev);

result->alloc = malloc( result->count * sizeof result->alloc[0] );
if (result->alloc) {
  for (cnt = 0; cnt <  result->count; cnt++ ) result->alloc[cnt] = cnt;
  }
return result;

failfree:
free (fwd);
free (rev);
free (result);
return NULL;
}

char * read_complete_file(char *name, size_t *sizep)
{
int fd, rc;
size_t size, len;
char *result;

struct stat st;

fd = open(name, O_RDONLY);

if (fd == -1) goto fail;
rc = fstat(fd, &st);
if (rc == -1) goto closefail;
result = malloc (1+st.st_size );
if (!result ) goto closefail;
result[st.st_size] = 0;

for (size = 0; size < st.st_size;) {
  rc = read(fd, result, st.st_size - size);
  if (rc < 0) goto freeclosefail;
  size += rc;
  }

fprintf(stderr, "Read %lu bytes FROM %s\n"
  , (unsigned long) size, name);
close(fd);
*sizep = size;
return result;

freeclosefail:
  free(result);
closefail:
  close(fd);
fail:
  *sizep=0; return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The file size can be up to 60GB. And there are 2 to 4 of them. Couldn't load the whole file in memory even if I wanted

Comment: If you're mapping the human genome, you can probably afford a 64 bits machine and mmap the entire file.

Comment: It's a college project, I'm not actually mapping human genome (I don't even know if it's human... ). I could for sure create a smaller test file that fits on my 4gb laptop, but at the moment I'm more interested in skipping those 3 lines. I don't think that when dealing with billions of bytes of data skipping 3 lines in that way generates a performance bottleneck.. I find it easier that way. I can't believe there's no easy way to do that in C

Comment: It is not impossible to do this kind of stuff on a home-PC. 64 bits is not that uncommon. But: you only to remember the last few lines, one or two. for the > lines: just crunch them into 4 bases per byte and write them to a binary file. You won't need more than a few KB of bufferspace. Could be done on a C64, given enough disk-capacity ;-)

Comment: I have to work with both FastQ and FastA file. I already successfully implemented the FastQ part (and it works, tested), now I'm almost done with the FastA too... I cannot see why you say you can't do with an home-pc. As I said I'm not sequencing genoma, I only have to eliminate some duplicates :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the position at any given point. It's really helpful when you checking the null in while condition, but after come inside you want to set the cursor back to previous line.**

fpos_t position;

```
fgetpos (file, &position);
```

Then Can set back to the same position:

```
fsetpos (file, &position);
```

Please follow the docs, It's tried and tested , working fine.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetpos/